# rsync: how to keep a selected target directory permissions?

Tags: permissions, rsync

What I couldn't figure out is how to sync local files to remote host, while leaving remote folder permissions for a particular folder /var/www/site1/home/images intact, which is 750, while source folder permissions are 770. I need this folder apache-writable locally,
but it shouldn't be writable on production server. And I need to keep target permissons only for this folder, for all other files and folders perms must be updated.

Thus far I was experimenting with --exclude, -filter but didn't get the desired effect.

```
rsync -av --delete /var/www/site1/ root@mysite.com:/var/www/site1/
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the rsync man page: `-a archive mode; same as -rlptgoD`.

`-p` is preserve permissions, so this should do what you want: `-vrltgoD`

Comment: Thank you! Still I need to update perms for all other files and folders.

Comment: So, I'd probably just do it with two commands, one for the main folder using `-av` and excluding the images folder (`--exclude /home/images/`) and then for the images folder use `-vrltgoD`. The `--dry-run` option is your friend when figuring these things out.